# cakephp - read 1 item from model + its related model + that model's related model?

Tags: cakephp

Invoice belongsTo Project
Project hasAndBelongsToMany Clients

How do I get say Invoice id # 23 with only the Project and the Clients linked to that Project by a HABTM relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use containable. In invoices controller:

> ```
> $this->Invoice->find('first',array(
>    'conditions'=>array('Invoice.id'=>23)
>    'contain'=>array('Project'=>array('Client'))
> ));
> ```

Comment: It gets the invoice and its Project, but not the next level: the Project's Clients (HABTM with Project).

Comment: Yes.  I attached it as a behavior to the Invoice model right before this.  The Client array ends up empty.

Comment: if there's a Client array in the result, it's working. You just don't have the data to fill in.